# OpenCL error: illegal implicit conversion between two pointers with different address spaces

Tags: opencl, atomic, local-variables

I have a function for float atomic_add:

```
inline void AtomicAdd(volatile __global float *source, const float operand)
{
    union{unsigned int intVal; float floatVal;} newVal;
    union{unsigned int intVal; float floatVal;} oldVal;

    do {
        oldVal.floatVal = *source;
        newVal.floatVal = oldVal.floatVal + operand;;
    }
    while (atomic_cmpxchg((volatile __global unsigned int *)source, oldVal.intVal, newVal.intVal) != oldVal.intVal);
}
```

Here is the main kernel, which calls the above function:

```
__kernel void main_kernel(__global float* image)
{
   AtomicAdd(&image[0], 1.0f); 
}
```

The above function run correctly. Now I want to introduce a local variable to force the AtomicAdd done in one work group once and for all:

```
__kernel void main_kernel(__global float* image)
{
   __local tmpSum[1];
   if(get_local_id(0)==0) { 
      tmpSum[0] = 0.0f; }

   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
   AtomicAdd(&tmpSum[0], 1.0f);
   barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

   AtomicAdd(&image[0], tmpSum[0]); 
}
```

The log gave following errors:

```
Build log: 
:422:15: error: illegal implicit conversion between two pointers with         different address spaces
                            AtomicAdd(&tmpSum[0], 1.0f);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
:422:15: warning: passing 'float __attribute__((address_space(3))) *' to parameter of type 'float volatile __attribute__((address_space(1))) *' discards qualifiers
                            AtomicAdd(&tmpSum[0], 1.0f);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
:17:49: note: passing argument to parameter 'source' here
    inline void AtomicAdd(volatile __global float *source, const float operand)
```

As you can see, there seemed to be something wrong with the different address spaces between the global and local pointers. Does anyone has idea about what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to pass `__local` pointer into function taking `__global` pointer and vice versa. The copy of AtomicAdd function is needed taking `__local` pointer in order to build the kernel successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I put my solution here. As pointed by doqtor, __local has different address space from _global. So the easiest way is overloading, which unfortunately opencl do not support. I have to define a new inline function and problem solved.